# deleting a key from a python DiskCache Fanout Cache

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to understand how to delete keys out of a memoized database call using python DiskCache package. Below is a simple function, that shows how I am memoizing a simple function call, and it works fine, with subsequent calls running much faster.

The documentation says that I can delete specific keys, but I can't see what the key is when it was generated using the memoize decorator

I'd have guessed that it was something like 
cache.pop(("__main__slowfunc", 5)), and while this doesn't throw an error, it doesn't remove the key from the cache.

```
from diskcache import FanoutCache
from pathlib import Path
import os
import time

local = Path(os.environ["AllUsersProfile"]) / "CacheTests" 
cacheLocation = local / "cache"
cache = FanoutCache(cacheLocation, timeout=1)

@cache.memoize()
def slowfunc(iterations):
    for i in range(0, iterations):
        time.sleep(1)    

iterations = 6

start = time.time()
slowfunc(iterations)
end = time.time()
print(f"Initial Call = {round(end-start,0)}s")
```

Any assistance appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Hi Dave, I see in your example that you have `iterations = 6`, but you say that you were trying `cache.pop(("__main__slowfunc", 5))` with a 5 for the iterations parameter. It might just be that mismatch that caused the problem.

Comment: It looks like DiskCache uses SQLite for its storage. If you have a SQLite viewer, it is possible to see the keys that are actually stored though they take a bit of deciphering.

Answer (score 2):

Great question, and it's really confusing how your example doesn't work given that it matches what the source code of disk cache appears to do.

I've extended the example a bit and it seems to work for me like this. See if this works for you:

```
from diskcache import FanoutCache
from pathlib import Path
import os
import time

local = Path(os.environ["AllUsersProfile"]) / "CacheTests" 
cacheLocation = local / "cache"
cache = FanoutCache(cacheLocation, timeout=1)

@cache.memoize()
def slowfunc(iterations):
    print("Recalculating")
    for i in range(0, iterations):
        time.sleep(1)    

iterations = 3

cache.delete(("__main__slowfunc", iterations))

start = time.time()
slowfunc(iterations)
end = time.time()
print(f"Initial Call = {round(end-start,0)}s")

start = time.time()
slowfunc(iterations)
end = time.time()
print(f"Subsequent Call = {round(end-start,0)}s")

cache.delete(("__main__slowfunc", iterations))

start = time.time()
slowfunc(iterations)
end = time.time()
print(f"After deletion = {round(end-start,0)}s")
```

Results:

```
Recalculating
Initial Call = 3.0s
Subsequent Call = 0.0s
Recalculating
After deletion = 3.0s
```

I tried it with pop instead of delete and that worked too

Answer (score 0):

I am using a slightly different approach to get correct cache key. Diskcache provides `__cache_key__()` method on the decorated function, which can be used for retrieving cache key of given function and given argument values. This way the code is less error prone, since I do not depend on the internal implementation details of diskcache cache key format.

```
cache_key = slowfunc.__cache_key__(iterations)
cache.delete(cache_key)
```